# Caller ID from iPad message shows "Home"

Tags: ipad

When I send a text message from my iPad, which is synced to my iPhone, I see that the caller ID on the iPhone is "Home".  How can I ensure that text messages from my iPad show my name or phone number instead of home?

Comment: It shows home because you have that number stored in your contacts as home.  It doesn't say home for anyone except you when using your devices.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "Caller ID" as it's not visible to anyone but you.

It's only shown on your iPhone because the phone number (or Apple ID) is in the Contacts of the device with the name set to Home. This means that messages received show the name of the sender pulled from Contacts, just like any other contact on the phone.

If you don't want this, delete the contact from your phone which contains the phone number, but this will delete it from all iCloud synchronised devices and can cause problems if it is your 'Me card' such as incorrect AutoFill information in Safari.